# Where is coagulation factor v produced?

Tags: blood-circulation

My textbook (Physiology 9th edition, People's Medical Publishing House, Beijing) tells me that coagulation factor V is produced in endothelial cells and platelets, which is different from some other books (saying in liver). So where exactly is it produced? Or is it just not quite clear?

Comment: Why the downvote? Surely a very good question?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I somewhat suspect the reason is that the question fails to demonstrate the basic biological knowledge to know that the liver is made of cells, including endothelial cells.

Answer (score 2):

Factor V is indeed mainly produced in liver ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_V)), which releases it into blood plasma.

But platelets are also an important source of factor V and "may account for "~25% of the circulating factor V" ([ref 1](https://www.jbc.org/article/S0021-9258(17)46373-3/fulltext))

*Platelet* factor V is synthesized in [megakaryocytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megakaryocyte) ([ref 1](https://www.jbc.org/article/S0021-9258(17)46373-3/fulltext)), which of course are the bone marrow cells responsible for the production of platelets.

The following reference gives a much more detailed explanation of factor V

Reference (available as [free pdf](https://www.jbc.org/action/showPdf?pii=S0021-9258%2817%2946373-3))

```
Factor V Is Complexed with Multimerin in Resting Platelet Lysates and Colocalizes
with Multimerin in Platelet α-Granules *

Catherine P.M. Hayward
Emilia Furmaniak-Kazmierczak
Anne-Marie Cieutat
Michael E. Nesheim
John G. Kelton **
Graham Côté
```

[Journal of Biological Chemistry (1995) Vol 270, pp19217-19224](https://doi.org/10.1074/jbc.270.33.19217)

Answer (score 2):

The coagulation factor 5 is primarly produced in the liver, meaning that the liver isn't the only place where this factor can be produced (F5 can possibly be produced by megakaryocytes too). After it is manufactured it circulates in an inactive form and is then converted into the active form with the help of thrombin and is able to attach to platelets. However, as far as I know, factor v is not produced in endothelial cells, there are a few factors that are, like Von Willebrand factor (VWF), factor VIII, thrombomodulin, endothelin etc., but F5 is  not one of them.